# Bootstrap pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to pull the text to the right, but it's not happening. I've spend over 2 hours on the same, but still no luck. What wrong am I doing. I'm using Bootstrap3. Following is my code and jsFiddle.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href=''><h3>Ask a Question </h3></a>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <a href='' class="tag">ABCD</a>
        <a href='' class="tag">ABCD</a>
        <a href='' class="tag">ABCD</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right time">
        <span class="asked_time"> asked  2 mins ago</span>
        <a href="" class="questioner"> Praful Bagai </a> <span class="questioner_points"> 2300</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`asked 2 mins ago` should move to the right. 
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emg0xkek/2/)

Comment: Do you mean that `asked 2 mins ago` should move to the right of the username?

Comment: No. the whole div should move to the right. Tags should remain on the left and `time` div on the right.

Comment: isn't it already to the right? atleast for me. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @K3v1n - I want it in the extreme right.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/emg0xkek/8/

Comment: i guess the other answers fit your description

Comment: Well, adding `col-xs-12` to table does not work. You can verify in the fiddle I provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125288/discussion-between-k3v1n-and-pythonenthusiast).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the table. 
Give it a `width:100%;` and remove the `float:left;` on the **td**.

```
table {width:100%;}
td {float:left; /* remove this /*
```

Working **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/emg0xkek/4/)**

Or instead of removing the `float:left;` give the **td** a width in `px` or `%`.

**Update after comment from K3v1n:**

Add the class to your table like: (instead of using css to give it 100%)

```
<table class="col-xs-12">
```

Comment: he is using bootstrap. better to use the inbuilt class `col-xs-12` for 100% width

Comment: giving table width as 100% or using `col-xs-12` does not solves the problem.

Comment: The demo link that you provided does not work if `float:left` is kept.

Comment: I want to keep `float:left` because it break some things which I'm not able to replicate on jsfiddle.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast can you add `width:100%;` to the td?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="col-xs-12">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href=''><h3>Ask a Question </h3></a>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <a href='' class="tag">ABCD</a>
        <a href='' class="tag">ABCD</a>
        <a href='' class="tag">ABCD</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right time">
        <span class="asked_time"> asked  2 mins ago</span>
        <a href="" class="questioner"> Praful Bagai </a>   <span class="questioner_points"> 2300</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to give `width: 100%;` to `<table>` tag

`col-xs-12` is an bootstrap class which give the table 100% width

Comment: he is using bootstrap. better to use the inbuilt class col-xs-12 for 100% width

Comment: giving table width as 100% or using `col-xs-12` does not solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img src="..." alt="..." class="pull-right">
```

**Please check this link:-http://code.makery.ch/library/more-html-css/image-bootstrap/**

Answer (score 0):

Add the class of '.table' to your table and remove the 'float:left' on the TD.

https://jsfiddle.net/emg0xkek/11/

```
<table class="table">
...
</table>

td{

}
```